# how to create div elements with button

Tags: javascript

This is my first time in javascript. I am creating a todo list and I have some problem with redact new todo element. I can delete elements. I can check elements if they are done. But when I try to edit them, only the first element is edited. Here is my source code.

```js
var list = document.querySelector('div');
list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'li') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
  }
}, false);


function newElement(newChild) {
    let btnDel= document.createElement("button");
    let myEd = document.getElementById("myEdit");
    let spanClose1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
    let spanRedact = document.getElementsByClassName("redact")[0];
    let myDel = document.getElementById("myDelete");
    let spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    let spanYes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes")[0];
    //create button
    let divWithBut = document.createElement("div");
    divWithBut.className = "forButt";
    let btnRedact = document.createElement("button");
    btnRedact.className = "fa fa-pencil";
    btnRedact.id = "redactBut1";
    //redact but
    btnRedact.onclick = function(){
    myEd.style.display = "block";
    let editText = document.getElementById("editText");
    let divWithText = document.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
    editText.value = divWithText.innerHTML;
    spanRedact.onclick = function(){
        divWithText.textContent = editText.value;
        divWithText.className = "todoPost";
        myEd.style.display = "none";
    };
    spanClose1.onclick = function() {
        myEd.style.display = "none";
    };
}
    
    /*done but*/
    let doneBut = document.createElement("button");
    doneBut.className = "fa fa-check-circle-o";
      
    divWithBut.appendChild(btnRedact);
    divWithBut.appendChild(doneBut);
    divWithBut.appendChild(btnDel);
    /******************/

    //create arrow
    let divWithArrow = document.createElement("div");
    divWithArrow.className = "myArrow";
    let arrowUP = document.createElement("i");
    arrowUP.className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
    let arrowDown = document.createElement("i");
    arrowDown.className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowUP);
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowDown);

    //for date
    let date = new Date().toDateString();
    let divTime = document.createElement("div");
    divTime.className = "myTime";
    divTime.innerHTML = date.toString();
    //***************************/
    let div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "timeComent";
    let myli = document.createElement("li");
    myli.className = "todoPost";
    let addField = document.getElementById("addField").value;
    let t = document.createTextNode(addField);
    myli.appendChild(t);
    div1.appendChild(divTime);
    divWithArrow.style.display = "flex";
    div1.appendChild(divWithArrow);
    div1.appendChild(myli);
    divWithBut.style.display = "flex";
    div1.appendChild(divWithBut);

    if (addField === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        t = document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(div1);
    }   
    document.getElementById("addField").value = "";
    //delete but
    btnDel.className = "fa fa-trash-o";
    btnDel.onclick = function(){
        myDel.style.display = "block";
        spanClose.onclick = function() {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanYes.onclick = function() {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
            div1.remove();
        };
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{

    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.firstBar{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.fafaArrow{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
}
.timeComent{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}
.numberpost{
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(141, 112, 112);
}
.todoPost{
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.shadow {
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.window {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #0000cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #0000cc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
}
.shadow:target {display: block;}


.redact {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.redact:hover {
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;}
.close{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close:hover{
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}


.yes {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.yes:hover{
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;
}

.close1{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close1:hover{
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
div li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  
  /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
  div li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TO DO List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <input id="addField" type="text" size="70%" placeholder="Task" name="Task">
    <button type="button" onclick="newElement()">Add</button>
</header>
<div>
    <div class="firstBar">
        <div class="fafaArrow">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            <input class="inptxt" type="text" size="50%" name="Task">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <ul id="forToDo">
        <li class="timeComent">
            <div class="myTime"></div>
            <div class="myArrow"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="myDelete" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">Delete item?<br>
        <span class="yes">Yes</span>
        <span class="close">No</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myEdit" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">
        Edit text?<br>
        <label>
            <textarea id="editText"></textarea>
        </label>
        <span class="redact">Save</span>
        <span class="close1">Cancel</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Do not blame at me, please. I see this language first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code could be refactored heavily, but the main issue is here:

```
let divWithText = document.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
```

This is looking up the first todo item and setting it as the one to be modified, regardless of which row the redact button click is initiated from. What you need to do is reference the specific todo item the user is clicking the redact/edit button on, which you can do by referencing the parent element of the div the buttons are in. So change:

```
btnRedact.onclick = function (){
    //...
    let divWithText = document.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
    //...
}
```

To:

```
btnRedact.onclick = function (){
    //...
    let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
    //...
}
```

---

Your code, updated:

```js
var list = document.querySelector('div');
list.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
    if (ev.target.tagName === 'li') {
        ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
    }
}, false);


function newElement(newChild) {
    let btnDel = document.createElement("button");
    let myEd = document.getElementById("myEdit");
    let spanClose1 = document.getElementsByClassName("close1")[0];
    let spanRedact = document.getElementsByClassName("redact")[0];
    let myDel = document.getElementById("myDelete");
    let spanClose = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    let spanYes = document.getElementsByClassName("yes")[0];
    //create button
    let divWithBut = document.createElement("div");
    divWithBut.className = "forButt";
    let btnRedact = document.createElement("button");
    btnRedact.className = "fa fa-pencil";
    btnRedact.id = "redactBut1";
    //redact button
    btnRedact.onclick = function () {
        myEd.style.display = "block";
        let editText = document.getElementById("editText");
        let divWithText = divWithBut.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("todoPost")[0];
        editText.value = divWithText.innerHTML;
        spanRedact.onclick = function () {
            divWithText.textContent = editText.value;
            divWithText.className = "todoPost";
            myEd.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanClose1.onclick = function () {
            myEd.style.display = "none";
        };
    }

    /*done but*/
    let doneBut = document.createElement("button");
    doneBut.className = "fa fa-check-circle-o";

    divWithBut.appendChild(btnRedact);
    divWithBut.appendChild(doneBut);
    divWithBut.appendChild(btnDel);
    /******************/

    //create arrow
    let divWithArrow = document.createElement("div");
    divWithArrow.className = "myArrow";
    let arrowUP = document.createElement("i");
    arrowUP.className = "fa fa-chevron-up";
    let arrowDown = document.createElement("i");
    arrowDown.className = "fa fa-chevron-down";
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowUP);
    divWithArrow.appendChild(arrowDown);

    //for date
    let date = new Date().toDateString();
    let divTime = document.createElement("div");
    divTime.className = "myTime";
    divTime.innerHTML = date.toString();
    //***************************/
    let div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.className = "timeComent";
    let myli = document.createElement("li");
    myli.className = "todoPost";
    let addField = document.getElementById("addField").value;
    let t = document.createTextNode(addField);
    myli.appendChild(t);
    div1.appendChild(divTime);
    divWithArrow.style.display = "flex";
    div1.appendChild(divWithArrow);
    div1.appendChild(myli);
    divWithBut.style.display = "flex";
    div1.appendChild(divWithBut);

    if (addField === '') {
        alert("You must write something!");
    } else {
        t = document.getElementById("forToDo").appendChild(div1);
    }
    document.getElementById("addField").value = "";
    //delete but
    btnDel.className = "fa fa-trash-o";
    btnDel.onclick = function () {
        myDel.style.display = "block";
        spanClose.onclick = function () {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
        };
        spanYes.onclick = function () {
            myDel.style.display = "none";
            div1.remove();
        };
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{

    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.firstBar{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.fafaArrow{
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #000;
}
.timeComent{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
}
.numberpost{
    padding: 5px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background: rgb(141, 112, 112);
}
.todoPost{
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: justify;
}
.shadow {
    background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
.window {
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid #0000cc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #0000cc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background: #fff;
}
.shadow:target {display: block;}


.redact {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.redact:hover {
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;}
.close{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close:hover{
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}


.yes {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.yes:hover{
    background-color: #68f462;
    color: white;
}

.close1{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #0000cc;
    color: #0000cc;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #f2f2f2;
    font-size: 14pt;
    cursor:pointer;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close1:hover{
    background-color: #f44336;
    color: white;
}

/* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
div li.checked {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: line-through;
  }
  
  /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
  div li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TO DO List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <input id="addField" type="text" size="70%" placeholder="Task" name="Task">
    <button type="button" onclick="newElement()">Add</button>
</header>
<div>
    <div class="firstBar">
        <div class="fafaArrow">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-up" ></i>
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            <input class="inptxt" type="text" size="50%" name="Task">
            <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <ul id="forToDo">
        <li class="timeComent">
            <div class="myTime"></div>
            <div class="myArrow"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
<div id="myDelete" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">Delete item?<br>
        <span class="yes">Yes</span>
        <span class="close">No</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myEdit" class="shadow">
    <div class="window">
        Edit text?<br>
        <label>
            <textarea id="editText"></textarea>
        </label>
        <span class="redact">Save</span>
        <span class="close1">Cancel</span>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```